# AJAX not submitting checkbox values to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I originally built the form using [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form) but now I need to add a checkbox for signing up to a newsletter. I've tried several fixes I have found already but none seem to be working correctly, and I'm quite new to PHP,AJAX,jQuery. It's been super frustrating :/

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="form-messages"></div>
<form class="green-txt" id="ajax-contact" method="post" action="mailer.php">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="name">Name:</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="email">Email:</label>
     <input type="email" class="form-control email-in" id="email" name="email" placeholder="" required>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group form-inline">
     <label for="subscribe">Subscribe: </label>
     <input class="sub-btn" type="checkbox" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
    <button type="submit" class="btn-success btn btn-submit">Send</button>
    </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

The js:

```js
$(function() {

// Get the form.
var form = $('#ajax-contact');

// Get the messages div.
var formMessages = $('#form-messages');

// Set up an event listener for the contact form.
$(form).submit(function(e) {
 // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
 e.preventDefault();

 // Serialize the form data.
 var dataString = $(form).serialize();

 // Submit the form using AJAX.
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $(form).attr('action'),
  data: dataString
 })
 .done(function(response) {
  // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'success' class.
  $(formMessages).removeClass('error');
  $(formMessages).addClass('success');

  // Set the message text.
  $(formMessages).text(response);

  // Clear the form.
  $('#name').val('');
  $('#email').val('');

 })
 .fail(function(data) {
  // Make sure that the formMessages div has the 'error' class.
  $(formMessages).removeClass('success');
  $(formMessages).addClass('error');

  // Set the message text.
  if (data.responseText !== '') {
   $(formMessages).text(data.responseText);
  } else {
   $(formMessages).text('Oops! An error occured and your message could not be sent.');
  }
 });

});

});
```

And the PHP:

```html
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
   $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $subscribe = trim($_POST["subscribe"]);


    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "UP News New Contact - $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
    $subscribe = "Subscribe: $subscribe\n";



    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You!";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```

What Can I do here to make it process the checkbox data?

Comment: its submitting. But only if the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. its submitting only when its checked.

You can change you code

```
$subscribe = trim($_POST["subscribe"]);
```

to

```
$subscribe = isset($_POST["subscribe"]) ? 'Yes' : 'No' ;
```

**EDIT:**
Change the line $subscribe = "Subscribe: $subscribe\n"; will be $email_content .= "Subscribe: $subscribe\n"

Comment: Thank you for this, it has helped! I also figured out why it wasn't showing up in the email, I had made an error using "$subscribe" where it should've said "$email_content".

Comment: You have assigned the variable $subscribe twice. The change was for the first time you assigned it.

Comment: You need to check if the value of $_POST["subscribe"] is coming to your php code. use isset() function. 
Check code in my answer below

Comment: also, the line $subscribe = "Subscribe: $subscribe\n"; will be $email_content .= "Subscribe: $subscribe\n";

Comment: I saw my error just as you guys posted, thank you for pointing it out. Can't believe I missed it before now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value of $_POST["subscribe"] is coming to your php code.
use isset() function to do so...

Edited your script, should work fine now.

```html
// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
   $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    //$subscribe = trim($_POST["subscribe"]);
    $subscribe = (isset($_POST["subscribe"]))?"Yes":"No";


    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
        exit;
    }

    // Set the recipient email address.
    // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
    $recipient = "";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "UP News New Contact - $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n";
    $subscribe = "Subscribe: $subscribe\n";



    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You!";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

} else {
    // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
    http_response_code(403);
    echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
}
```